# Kubernetes (Google) insufficient CPU and memory during deployment, autopilot cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Any idea why I just started getting "Insufficient CPU" and Insufficient memory" when deploying containers (nodejs api and cloud sql proxy) to Kubernetes.

This has worked fine before, I have set the resource limits in the yaml but even if I remove those I get same error.
I have deleted the workload from google console and redeployed the deployment yaml from the command line.

Very strange because this has worked before

The cluster is set to Autopilot mode

Comment: Please let us know whether your query is reolved or not?

Comment: This is resolved, I recreated the cluster and it started working. Quite strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure this out so I deleted and recreated the cluster. Strange.